# How do I read a file in App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a file at `/WEB-INF/config.txt` on app engine.  What is the path to the file on app engine?

eg: `new File(/*What path do i put here?*/)`

Comment: In my understanding files aren't allowed on AppEngine. You have to declare them as static files and access them via the URL. http://blabla.appspot.com/YOURFILE.txt

Comment: Files can be read, not written.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This worked for me:

`servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config.txt")`

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I didn't have access to **ServletContext** - getServletContext():

This worked for me:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("WEB-INF/config.txt"));
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. One thing to stress is that if you're doing it this way, you don't put a "/" before "WEB-INF" in "WEB-INF/config.txt".

Answer (score 5):

There's some documentation at appengine [how to add resources to your project](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_files_and_resource_files). Check out the <resource-files> part. Some further information can be read in [the description of the appengine sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox).

When the resources are added to your project you can use the following code to read their content:

```
File f = new File("path/below/my/project/directory/config.txt");
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);
```

In the above example the 'path' directory is below your project's 'war' directory.

Answer (score 3):

I found this to be a good way to grab the entire file in a String:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import com.google.common.io.CharStreams;

URL resource = getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/config.txt");
File file = new File(resource.toURI());
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
String myString = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is part of your application and on the classpath, you should be able to load it using this.getClass().getResource().

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your files in `src/main/resources`:

[image]

2. Grant access to that folder by adding this in `appengine-web.xml`:

```
<resource-files>
    <include path="/resources" />
</resource-files>
```

3. Use in your code as normal. For example:

```
URL resource = EmailSender.class.getClassLoader().getResource("email-template.html");
if (resource != null) {
    File tempFile = new File(resource.getFile());
    if (tempFile.exists()) {
        htmlMessage = FileUtils.readFileToString(tempFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```