# How to read write xml file in Google App Engine Project?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

We are developing an application in Google app engine using Java.We have location.xml file in project. And there is location array field in table. We have to map location array with location.xml. Actually android and web application using the same xml file to show location in drop down.

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   (java.io.FilePermission gae:C:\NEW WORKSPACE\xml\input.xml write)

We are getting issues for file read and write. What can be solution for this issue?

Comment: as local resource file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8505665 - you can not write to the local filesystem (and there is certainly no C: drive) http://stackoverflow.com/a/2693092

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read a file in App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034420/how-do-i-read-a-file-in-app-engine)