# How can I impersonate a user of AppEngine java application operating in G-Suite domain?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authorization

My standard AppEngine application needs to perform changes in a Google Sheet documents (among others).

To achieve this, I need to obtain a credential for service account, and somehow configure that it should act in behalf of a user.

This method allows gives me default service account credentials:

```
private static GoogleCredential getDefaultServiceAccountCredential() throws IOException {
    return GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault()
        .createScoped(MY_SCOPES);
}
```

but it does not work in behalf of a user.

Following code is similar, uses other (non-default) service account, but still no impersonation happens:

```
private static GoogleCredential getNonDefaultServiceAccountCredential() throws IOException {
    return GoogleCredential.fromStream(IncomingMailHandlerServlet.class.getResourceAsStream("/tokens/anoher-e6351a8c5b91.json"))
        .createScoped(MY_SCOPES);
}
```

For impersonation, [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#impersonation) (and many SO advices) mentions how to do it with use of PKCS12 file; however, that file can only be read as `PrivateKey` on installed application and not on AppEngine.

Is there any way to obtain impersonated credential for java application running in AppEngine?
Or, is there a trick to read from a `File` on AppEngine?

Note that, for all service accounts that I tried, I configured them with role Owner and with DwD (Domain-wide delegation). Is there anything else to configure?

Comment: Can't you perform the impersonation as the documentation you provided states, with the default (or non-default) service account by additionally calling [`GoogleCredential.Builder.setServiceAccountUser(String)`](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.Builder#setServiceAccountUser(java.lang.String)) after creating the `GoogleCredential` object?

Comment: In App Engine Flex you can make use of [env vars](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#Node.js_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables). You can (more like should) use Cloud Storage to [read and write files in App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage). Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034420/how-do-i-read-a-file-in-app-engine) as well for how to read a file in App Engine.

Comment: @Tudormi yes that was the first thing that I wanted to do, but did you ever try? There is no way of "additonally calling" that, or at least I did not find it. I will definitely appreciate a piece of code demonstrating how to use that note. I did not find it applicable.

Comment: To your second comment: Flex env is currently not an option for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [GoogleCredential reference](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.19.1/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential) offers a sample to

> also use the service account flow to impersonate a user in a domain that you own. This is very similar to the service account flow above, but you additionally call [GoogleCredential.Builder.setServiceAccountUser(String)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.19.1/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.Builder.html#setServiceAccountUser(java.lang.String))

```
 public static GoogleCredential createCredentialForServiceAccountImpersonateUser(
      HttpTransport transport,
      JsonFactory jsonFactory,
      String serviceAccountId,
      Collection<String> serviceAccountScopes,
      File p12File,
      String serviceAccountUser) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    return new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(transport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(serviceAccountScopes)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12File)
        .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccountUser)
        .build();
  }
```

There are multiple options on how to access a file from App Engine Standard. Below, you have two options explained:

---

Option 1: the `p12File` (credentials file) is an [App Engine Standard resource file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#resource_files). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8505665/3615567) to see how to access such files, code-wise. I strongly recommend this approach because

> These files are only available to your code on a read-only basis and not for traffic serving.

```
File f = new File("path/below/my/project/directory/credentials.json");
```

and the `appengine-web.xml` should define the resource files:

```
<resource-files>
  <include path="path/below/my/project/directory/credentials.json"/>
</resource-files>
```

---

Option 2: the credentials file is in Cloud Storage. This [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#reading_from_cloud_storage) explains how to reach files in Cloud Storage from App Engine Standard. But I believe it's too much of a hassle. I provided this option as well because I have mentioned it.

Comment: any idea how to use this on AppEngine standard environment? because afaik access to filesystem is not supported there

Comment: Sorry for the delay. IMHO you can go for [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#env_variables) or just use [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#reading_from_cloud_storage), to have a static file with secured access.

Comment: Hi @Tudormi can you change your code above to show how any of these options might be used on standard env?

Comment: Hi @PetrKozelka.
I found an easier (and I would say the proper) way to use [resource files in App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#resource_files). I will update the answer with 2 possibilities: resource files and Cloud Storage.

Comment: @PetrKozelka anytime! Let the community know how it goes :)