# Google Calendar Integration with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

I have a Google App Engine Service set up and running on a Google account A. What I would like to be able to do is book events on my business's Google Calendar account B. I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) as a general guide. Here are the steps I have done to do this (Note: the AppEngine is already running and functional.

1. Enabled the Calendar API in my Project for Google Account A
2. Gone to my account B's [admin console](https://admin.google.com/) and went to Security -> Advanced Settings -> Manage API Client access and authorized the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` to the id of my service for my App Engine in account A.
3. Code below in Go

Note: in the `getCalendarService`, I'm getting the credentials using [ADC](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) following this [repo's](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client) README

```golang
func getCalendarService() (*calendar.Service, error) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    return calendar.NewService(ctx, option.WithScopes(calendar.CalendarScope))
}

// code adapted from https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events/
func bookEvent() {
    srv, err := getCalendarService()
    if err != nil {logAndPrintError(err)}
    event := &calendar.Event{
        Summary: "Test Title",
        Description: "Lorem ipsum",
        Start: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: "2020-02-12T09:00:00-07:00",
            TimeZone: "America/Chicago",
        },
        End: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: "2020-02-12T17:00:00-07:00",
            TimeZone: "America/Chicago",
        },
    }
    calendarId := "primary"
    event, err = srv.Events.Insert(calendarId, event).Do()
    if err != nil {
        logAndPrintError(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Event created: %s\n", event.HtmlLink)
}
```

When I look in log and error reporting there is no error, and the logs show this message:

> Event created: *a Calendar URL*

but when I copy the link and go to my Google Account B and load it, Google Calendar says "Could not find the requested event". It is worth mentioning that if I load the url into Account A, it says the same thing.

For some reason there is no error, but the event does not work. I don't think it is a problem in my code but a problem in the credentials, but I could be wrong.

---

**Note:** I'm not downloading any keys, I'm using ADC with App Engine to get my credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken,

> you creating a calendar event with a Service account and insert this
>   event into the primary calendar OF THE SERVICE ACCOUNT

This is probably not what you wanted,instead, if you want to insert the event into your primary calendar either

- You need to specify the id of this calendar as `calendarId` instead of primary - this implies that your share your calendar with the service account beforehand
- Or, you use [impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegate-domain-wide-authority), that is build the the service account service in such a way that it acts as you (or another user of your domain specified as the `ServiceAccountUser`

Comment: In my question I said that I followed that impersonation link as a guide when I was setting it up. What can I do different? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide your code snippet that includes the creation of the service including impersonation?

Comment: I'm slightly confused, the only code I used in the impersonation was the `getCalendar()` function. To set up impersonation I did Step 2 in my question where I authorize my service's ID with the needed calendar scope.

Comment: Did you write a code which would be equivalent to [Delegate domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegate-domain-wide-authority) but in your language (go)?

Comment: I did not write that code. I think I just got the credentials for my service account for Account A, not B. Would I have to create a project for account B and in the project create a service to use here. Further, do I need to download the P12 creds or will App Engine manage those for me? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I am not very familiar with App Engine, but have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341317/how-can-i-impersonate-a-user-of-appengine-java-application-operating-in-g-suite). It is important to specify which user you impersonate, because the event will be created in the calendar of this user.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will attempt what you are saying and will upvote and accept once I get it working.

Comment: When I do this i get the error: `Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.`

Comment: how do i find the calendar id?